# Convert Erlang catch to Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

In Erlang, I can do something like

```
[catch X+1 || X <- [4,a,6], X > 3].
```

Get the result,

```
[5, {‘EXIT’, _}, 7]
```

Can someone tell me how can I get something similar in Elixir please?
I just cannot find the `catch` in Elixir

**UPDATE**

After some tries, I think I found the answer.

```
iex(3)> a = for i <- [4, :a, 6] do
...(3)>   try do
...(3)>     i+1
...(3)>   catch
...(3)>     error, reason ->
...(3)>       {error, reason}
...(3)>   end
...(3)> end
[5, {:error, :badarith}, 7]
```

Comment: For your information, there's quite a bit more about this here: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Expression `catch`](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#catch) is an older version of the `try` expression. It always returns something and catches all exceptions converting them to a term as stated in the documentation:

> For exceptions of class error, that is, run-time errors, {'EXIT',{Reason,Stack}} is returned.
>   For exceptions of class exit, that is, the code called exit(Term), {'EXIT',Term} is returned.
>   For exceptions of class throw, that is the code called throw(Term), Term is returned.

It's a construct of the language, its syntax, so would need to be implemented as such in Elixir (i.e. with the same semantic as in Erlang). From the documentation it seems that Elixir only supports the [`try` semantic](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html). The solution you proposed is a good workaround.